# How do Play controllers inject variables with the proper name into templates?

Tags: playframework

In the [Play getting started docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1RC3/guide3), they show this controller:

```java
public static void index() {
  Post frontPost = Post.find("order by postedAt desc").first();
  List<Post> olderPosts = Post.find("order by postedAt desc").from(1).fetch(10);
  render(frontPost, olderPosts);
}
```

Then, in the template the frontPost and olderPosts are used without any special mapping!

```html
<a href="#">${frontPost.title}</a>
```

How is Play preserving these names?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is made by code injection.

At compile, some classes are enhanced (with code injection, by **Javassist**), in order to add some informations, such as variable names.

In the render method, this operation is done by the "play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer.LocalVariablesNamesTracer" class.

Comment: This feature breaks when you pass objects that don't have names to render (example: render(Posts.findById(id))). The resulting error message is a simple NullPointerException in the template. Do you know if there is a good reason why the error message can't be more helpful in this case?